# File download with java - Files corrupted

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

Here is my code.i write this to download mp3 flies,video files & images.
i used FileOutputStream for handling files..
All files are downloading well..
mp3 files are working..but images and videos are corrupted

```
private void download(String fileURL, String destinationDirectory,String name) throws IOException {

        // File name that is being downloaded
        String downloadedFileName = name;
        // Open connection to the file
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);

        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        // Stream to the destionation file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationDirectory + "/" + downloadedFileName);

        // Read bytes from URL to the local file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        System.out.println("Downloading " + downloadedFileName);
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        // Close destination stream
        fos.close();
        // Close URL stream
        is.close();
    }
```

Comment: This code should work fine... But you should learn to open and close your resources correctly. In particular, use a try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your routine. Works fine for me.

I used the URL

"http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3"

and got a playable MP3 file of exactly 1,430,174 bytes.

Next I tried JPEG:

"http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/beautiful/beautiful-01.jpg"

works fine.

I suspect what happened is that you used URL of a web page instead of the audio/video/pic file by mistake. For example, if you used the URL

"http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beautiful/beautiful-01.jpg"

instead of the one above, you will not get a proper JPG. You'll have to use "View Image" or "Copy Image Location" in your browser.

Comment: this code works with mp3..but images and videos are corrupted

Comment: Does it work with "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/beautiful/beautiful-01.jpg" ?

Comment: Basically your routine should work, but I would used try-with-resources instead of close() and Buffered streams. Buffered streams are efficient, and you can copy with a simple

int c;
while ((c=is.read())!=-1) fos.write(c);

without bothering to create your own buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at such libraries as [Apache IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).
It has many helper methods such as [redirecting streams](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,

```
URLConnection con = new URL(fileURL).openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationDirectory + "/" + name));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fos.close();
```

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use BufferedOutputStream.

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos );
```

like this :

```
private void download(String fileURL, String destinationDirectory,String name) throws IOException {

        // File name that is being downloaded
        String downloadedFileName = name;
        // Open connection to the file
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);

        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        // Stream to the destionation file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationDirectory + "/" + downloadedFileName);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos );

        // Read bytes from URL to the local file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        System.out.println("Downloading " + downloadedFileName);
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        bos.flush();
        // Close destination stream
        bos.close();
        // Close URL stream
        is.close();
    }
```

Comment: "you need to flush": No, you don't.

Comment: you are right, The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.